# How can I type a newline using the LaTeX Graphviz package?

Tags: line-breaking, graphs

I am using the [Graphviz](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphviz?lang=en) package (`\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}`) for my LaTeX document.

I am unable to break lines in my nodes.

My code:

```
\digraph{contract}{
    rankdir = "LR";
    computeSumParam0[label = "computeSum: \\n param \#0"];
}
```

This renders the characters `\n` on the PDF literally.

If I instead use `\n`, LaTeX fails to compile because the command `\n` does not exist.

Comment: It seems that `\noexpand\n` works. But gigiair's method seems better.

Comment: @egreg I prefer your method better though. I'd accept it if you posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\noexpand\n`, or wrap it in a macro for better clarity:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

\begin{document}

\digraph{contract}{
    rankdir = "LR";
    computeSumParam0[label = "computeSum: \noexpand\n param \#0"];
}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

\newcommand{\gvnewline}{\noexpand\n}

\begin{document}

\digraph{contract}{
    rankdir = "LR";
    computeSumParam0[label = "computeSum: \gvnewline param \#0"];
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just create a new line in the label text!

```
\digraph{contract}{
 rankdir="LR";
 computeSumParam0[label="computeSum:
                         param \#0"];
  }
```

Comment: [No space](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645), please. You can [edit your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/569184/edit).